# How to make multistep query wizard form with last step - user registration in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, forms

How to make multistep (2 steps) query wizard form with last step - user registration in Laravel 9? No package and jQuery required, possible vanilla JavaScript.

**Not registered** visitor will press **"Create query"** button, and hi will get multistep wizard form. When visitor will press **"Finish"** button, system will save filled query form of visitor and same time will make visitor as **registered and logged user**.

**Multistep query wizard form**

**First step**

url:

```
http://localhost:80/queries/1
```

queries/query1.blade.php:

```html
<h1>Step 1 - Query details</h1>

<form action="POST" method="">

<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject"></input>

<label for="content">Content</label>
<textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>

<label for="price">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price"></input>

<label for="term">Term</label>
<input type="text" name="term"></input>

<label for="location">Location</label>
<input type="text" name="location"></input>

<button type="button" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</form>
```

**Second step**

url:

```
http://localhost:80/queries/1
```

queries/query2.blade.php:

```html
<h1>Step 2 - Registration</h1>

<form action="POST" method="">

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name"></input>

<label for="surname">Surname</label>
<input type="text" name="surname"></input>

<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="email"></input>

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password"></input>

<button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
<button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Finish</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Simplify this by adding every 'step' to the same `blade` view and then use JavaScript to show/hide sections based on the users' stage within the process.

Comment: How to realize request validation?

Comment: In your `Controller` as you normally would.